# Showing all broadcast events on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

is it somehow possible to show all broadcast events/intents that are triggered in android? I just want to know if I can quickly figure out if an application is using intents/broadcasts I can hook into. For most of the stock android applications I can read the source but is time consuming.

Comment: If the "broadcast intents/events" are not documented, please don't use them. They are not intended for third party developers to connect to, may change when the apps get updated, may violate EULAs or other license agreements, etc.

Comment: A better approach would be to ask the developers of the applications and see if they agree to consider some intents/broadcasts "public", i.e. they promise not to change them so other apps can continue to use them.

Comment: And there's of course the crowd-sourced registry at openintents.org, but it's unfortunately not very populated yet.

Comment: I wanted to know if the internal music player of my telephone (motorola defy) sends broadcasts if the track changes. Guess it is not as simply as I hoped

Answer (score 43, accepted):

List all historical broadcasts and registered broadcast receivers with the following terminal command:

```shell
$ adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts
```

Comment: Or better: `dumpsys activity broadcasts history`

Answer (score 5):

Please check this open source project to see all broadcasts on your android phone:[Broadcasts Monitor Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger)

Answer (score 3):

There's logcat, which you can get to from the ddms (either the dedicated app, or the eclipse view), it should list all broadcasts, as well as the properties that are associated with the intent.  However, as the other commenters on your post have stated, you really shouldn't be doing that unless the intent has been published.  It may change, or cause other forms of havoc.  Although I disagree with the statement, some people may even go so far as to say that it's illegal if the licenses aren't compatible.  (Although I'm of the party that it's not, seeing as you're not statically linking to the code, nor even putting it in your package).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but logcat will NOT show the Broadcasts sent.  It does show Activity intents (the ones sent with startActivity), with a log like this: "I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent ...".

Comment: And just to be clear: it could be useful to show all the broadcasts sent in the system, just for debugging purposes, even if you don't intend to use undocumented ones in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I found was [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsInVrLmNvLmFzaHRvbmJyc2MuYW5kcm9pZC5pbnRlbnRpbnRlcmNlcHQiXQ..) that catches the intent on the fly and allow you to inspect the content